# Force upload with several google appengine applications sharing files

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two Google App Enginge application id:s, let's say App1 and App2. App1 is version for beta testers, App2 is public version of the same application. Idea is to deploy application first with application id 'App1', beta test it, and then deploy the same application with application id 'App2'.

I have problems with this sequence:

1. I do changes for beta testing and deploy it to App1 -> All changed
   files deployed OK
2. Beta testing is done using App1 -> Beta testers are happy
3. I deploy the same application (just change application id in
   Eclipse's 'Deploy to App Engine' dialog) to App2, because I want it
   public. Now the problem is that no files are deployed. Is the reason
   that there are already the same files deployed to app engine? But
   they are in App1, so App2 does not work.

Any suggestions how to do force upload for all files? Or any other way around this problem?

BR, Seppo

Answer (score 0):

Try also altering the version to something not previously used when deploying to the second Application ID.  Alternatively it may help to delete the version you're about to deploy to (although you cannot delete the default version).  Such changes might flush some cache in Eclipse of assumptions about what was previously deployed.

The uploader seems to transfer only what is newer than the destination.  That suggests another potential cause of your problem.  Your symptoms might occur if the local computer's clock is somewhat behind the one in AppEngine.  It is not very likely, but possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that using a new version number is not helping with the issue, though.

But if I deploy from different computer I got all files uploaded, it's good enough solution for me now. Maybe uploaded files are cached somewhere, I'm not sure.